# Chrome Extension Content Script to access chrome.storage

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created a custom menu that is appended to a page using Chrome Extensions Content Script. The extension works great and menu appear just as I wanted.

I want to go a little further and add a options page with a on/off switch that will define the var **menuToggle** to either 1 or 0, and that var will be attached to an IF condition:

```
IF menuToggle == 1 // Do something 
ELSE // console.log("var is 0, menu not loaded");
```

I was able to make this work on the extension environment using **"localstorage.menuToggle = 1;"**, but I understand that this will only work for the instance inside my extension and that the Content Script will not be able to access this var.

I went through the [official docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) for the chrome.storage API but honestly, I didn't understand much since I'm on early stage of programming.

From what I saw I should use the **chrome.storage.sync.set** for this, but I didn't quite get how to set this properly and either how to retrieve the data once inside the content script. I tried something like bellow, but it didn't work :

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'menuToggle': '1'}, function(){});
```

Question here: Do I need to define a function after the sync.set? Is it possible to just store the data without any function after it?

Bellow is the code that I used with the **localstorage**:

```
var varMenuToggleDefault = 1;
localStorage.varMenuToggle = 1;

$("input:checkbox[name=onoffswitch]").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    localStorage.varMenuToggle = varMenuToggleDefault;
    console.log('Switch is ON');
    console.log("Var is: " + localStorage.varMenuToggle);
  } else {
    localStorage.varMenuToggle = "0";
    console.log('Switch is OFF');
    console.log("Var is: " + localStorage.varMenuToggle);
  }

if (localStorage.varMenuToggle == 1) {
 // Load the menu
} else {
 // console.log("varMenuToggle is 0. Menu NOT loaded");
};
```

What I'm doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.storage` functions are asynchronous. The function after the brackets is called a callback function, and fires when the operation is complete. You don't have to have a callback function.

Getting your data back is a bit different. You can access your data this way:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("menuToggle", function(data) {
    var menuToggle = data.menuToggle;
}
```

Because the functions are asynchronous, if you want to get data back, you **must** have a callback function. The callback function receives an object that has a `menuToggle` property, which contains the value you set.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the quick and easy reply. From what I understand, since I first need to request the **sync.get** to retrieve the value, I'd need to insert my if condition within the content script inside the callback, after the var is retrieved, is that correct? Something like:

`chrome.storage.sync.get("menuToggle", function(data) {
    var menuToggle = data.menuToggle;
    if (menuToggle == 1) { do something }
}`

Comment: I struggled a bit testing this but with your help I manage to set and retrieve the value to add or not the menu. I don't know if it's the best way though, but I've used a Event Page to set the var for the first time after installment.